# 404 and 500 error views (404.html and 505.html) are not rendering when notFound() is called

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I've narrowed it down to when I have a route added:

/{userid}          Application.blah

Within the function (Application.blah), I thought I handled it by using notFoundIfNull(user)

My issue is whenever I enter a random URL into the website, I just get back the text 
"not found" in the production environment instead of the rendered 404.html page

Comment: did you created your own 404/500 pages or customized the existing ones? This should work in PROD mode...

Comment: What is `Accept:` header of the request that generates 404? If it is different than `text/html` and some other variations, it may try to render `404.tag` instead of `404.html`.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, Using this inside controllers.Application.java:

```
public static void blah (String userid)
{
    User test=null;
    try{
        test = User.findById(userid);
    } catch(Exception e)
    {
        //lookup exception!
    }
    notFoundIfNull(test);
}
```

With my route.conf containing this:

```
GET     /{userid}           Application.blah
```

I was able to view my /apps/views/errors/404.html which contained this:

```
#{if !play.mode.name() == 'DEV'}
  ...insert production 404 here...
#{/if}
```

If your format matches this then the issue may be something with what you're calling in the production 404. With my 403 page I found that if I call ${response.reason}, it rendered the whole page with just my 403 response as mentioned here: [How do I obtain the 'reason' for a forbidden()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630672/how-do-i-obtain-the-reason-for-a-forbidden). Good luck!