# How do I obtain the 'reason' for a forbidden()?

Tags: java, playframework-1.x

I'm designing my 403 page and I can't seem to obtain the 'reason' string which I am populating on various forbidden pages to give a more relative response to the issue at hand. If I type ${response.reason} in the template, the whole page gets replaced with just the text of the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code it seems that you can get this value in your template by doing

```
${result.getMessage()}
```

result is your Forbidden object that inherits from RuntimeException and the description you provide is passed to the base class as the exception message

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to provide any more reason the "Forbidden".  From a security standpoint, the user has attempted an unauthorized operation, and the last thing you want do is tell them exactly what's wrong (unknown user, invalid password, etc).  If you do this you are giving away information that could help the user penetrate your system.

For example, if you distinguish between unknown user and invalid password, you give away whether or not the userid exists.

Comment: For my setup, I disagree. My 403 pages are not reached for unknown user and invalid password. In those situations they are sent to the login page and prompted to log in. If they then log in and attempt to access a page that is restricted to them, this is when my 403 page shows up. For example: If a user is part of an organization, they have an 'edit organization' page. If they send that link to someone that is not part of that organization, I would like to send them to my forbidden page including "You are not part of this organization." as the 'reason'.

Comment: Just for a bit more clarity, I break my controllers down based on the security the user needs to access this information, in each of these controllers I have @Before methods that check to see if the given authenticated user has the appropriate permissions. If not I call forbidden("This is why you can't access the page.");